# Как отсортировать по алфавиту вывод содержимого директории. C(Си)

Tags: linux, c, строки, сортировка

При определенных обстоятельствах мне нужно получить список всех файлов из директорий, которые указаны в переменной окружения $PATH в linux и выводить их на экран последовательно.

Если открыть директорию с помощью opendir, а затем использовать readdir до NULL, то вывод имен файлов будет не отсортирован.

При нажатии tab с пустой строкой, установленный shell в linux выдает список всего "запускаемого" из переменной окружения $PATH и этот список отсортирован по алфавиту!

Вопрос в следующем: как грамотно это всё отсортировать по имени, а потом вывести? Как это делает тот же установленный shell в linux? Там будет более 2000 имен различной длинны...

Есть предположение:

1. Проверить количество всех файлов во всех директориях, выделить память под массив строк, снова идти по всем директориям добавляя каждое имя в массив, а затем отсортировать, потом выводить.
2. Нужно открыть сразу все директории из path, и на каждый итерации делать readdir из каждой директории до NULL, выбирать нужное имя, сравнивать с остальными, выводить, и снова и снова, зафиксировав уже выведенное имя и это кошмар в общем да...

Какой еще вариант может быть?

Comment: Соберите все в массив (можно динамически растущий, типа вектора из C++ — и тогда все будет за один проход. Кстати, так правильнее еще и потому, что а вдруг, пока вы пересчитывали, добавилось пару файлов?...) и сортируйте.

Comment: @Harry, realloc'ом имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Harry, спасибо. Понимаю способ через массив, вопрос задал с целью: может быть есть ещё какой-то способ реализовать этот вывод. Какой-то другой способ чтения директорий или с помощью каких-то сопровождающих функций.